# How to enable suggestions in an edittext programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have disabled the suggestions on my EditText when a certain character limit is reached using

```
mEditQuestionBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

I, however, need the suggestions capability back if the user were to press backspace and type again. Help?

**Essentially** It boils down to this. Is there an InputType available to enable the suggestions again? If not, can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT brings the suggestions back up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement onTextChanged() according to your need in addTextChangeListener on EditText.

```
mEditQuestionBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length()< threshold){
                mEditQuestionBox.setInputType(InputType. TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
            if(s.length()>= threshold){
                mEditQuestionBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just need the suggestions to come back up. How does this help?

Comment: in the onTextChanged measure the length of CharSequence "s" if it is less than the limit you set previously, you remove the flag you put. wait ill put the edited version

Comment: That's the question, how do I remove the flag once I've set it.

Comment: Auto complete flag doesn't bring the suggestions back. Can you think of something else?

Comment: Try InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT, if this doesn't work probably use AutoCompleteTextView it would provide better control.

Comment: CLASS_TEXT works. You can update your answer, I'll then upvote it. :)

Comment: What is threshold because from the code it is unknow and will come with error